# Please explain the output of this program based on pointers and strings?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, output

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int Track[]={10,20,30,40},*Striker;
Striker=Track;
Track[1]+=30;
cout<<"Striker >"<<*Striker<<endl;
*Striker-=10;
Striker++;
cout<<"Next @"<<*Striker<<endl;
Striker+=2;
cout<<"Last @"<<*Striker<<endl;
cout<<"Reset To"<<Track[0]<<endl;
getch();
}
```

The output for the program is 
Striker > 10
Next @ 50
Last @ 40
Reset To 0

Please explain the output of this program.Would be of great help in solving similar problems.Thanks in advance

Comment: Read up about pointers. There's a plethora of resources about them

Comment: I am being serious about pointers recently.And struggling a bit on strings.Please help if you can

Comment: @BhargabKakati There are no _strings_ in your example??

Comment: oops sorry.I mean Arrays.I overlooked it @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation line by line:

```
Striker=Track;
```

Sets Striker to point to the memory of Track, so Striker[0] would be equals to Track[0].

```
Track[1]+=30;
```

Increases the value of the second index of Track by 30 (Track[1] = 50).

```
cout<<"Striker >"<<*Striker<<endl;
```

*Striker is the same as Striker[0], *Stirker+1 is the same as Striker[1] and so on. The output of this line is "Striker > 10" because Striker[0] = Track[0] = 10.

```
*Striker-=10;
```

Decreases the value of the first index of Striker by 10 (Striker[0] = 0).

```
Striker++;
```

Increases Striker pointer, so now Striker points to Track+1 (Striker[0]=Track[1], Striker[1]=Track[2], ...).

```
cout<<"Next @"<<*Striker<<endl;
```

Outputs "Next @50" because Striker[0]=Track[1]=50.

```
Striker+=2;
```

Increases Striker 2 indexes. Now Striker=Track+3.

```
cout<<"Last @"<<*Striker<<endl;
```

Outputs "Last @40" because the value of Striker[0] is equals to the value of Track[3].

```
cout<<"Reset To"<<Track[0]<<endl;
```

Outputs "Reset To 0" because Track[0] changed to 0 when Striker[0] decreased (*Striker-=10).

All this pointers operations are explained in this tutorial:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Thank You very much .That really helped